# API Django + WebSockets

Tags: python, django, api, websocket

Я использую [API](https://rapidapi.com/chicmi/api/chicmi-local-fashion) и веб-сокеты в Django.
У меня есть HTML-форма, в которой я ввожу количество дней и максимальный результат, нажимаю кнопку, и ничего не происходит. При попытке открыть страницу на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/London`, браузер также пытается установить соединение с WebSockets, используя URL `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/London`, но сервер не может найти соответствующий обработчик для этого URL и возвращает **ошибку 404**.

Итак, мне нужно перенаправить клиента на страницу с данными показа мод после того, как клиент введет данные в форму. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте, как исправить ошибку:

```
[11/May/2023 20:55:04] "GET /events/London/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1676 Not Found: /ws/London/ [11/May/2023 20:55:04] "GET /ws/London/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4822
```

###### events.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Events</title>
    <script>
        var ws_url = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/' + '{{ city }}' + '/';
        var ws = new WebSocket(ws_url);
        ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            var event_data = JSON.parse(event.data)['event_data'];
            var event_list = document.getElementById('event-list');
            event_list.innerHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < event_data.length; i++) {
                var event = event_data[i];
                var event_element = document.createElement('div');
                event_element.innerHTML = '<h2>' + event['event_name'] + '</h2>' +
                                          '<img src="' + event['event_preview_url'] + '">' +
                                          '<p><a href="' + event['detail_url'] + '">More Info</a></p>' +
                                          '<p>' + event['location'] + '</p>';
                event_list.appendChild(event_element);
            }
        };

        function update_events() {
            var days = document.getElementById('days').value;
            var max_results = document.getElementById('max-results').value;
            var message = {
                'days': days,
                'max_results': max_results
            };
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Events in {{ city }}</h1>
    <p>Days: <input type="number" id="days" value="14"></p>
    <p>Max Results: <input type="number" id="max-results" value="5"></p>
    <button onclick="update_events()">Update</button>
    <div id="event-list"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

###### consumers.py:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import requests

class EventConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.city = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['city']
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.city,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.city,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        url = "https://chicmi.p.rapidapi.com/calendar_in_city/"
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "мой ключ API",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "chicmi.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        events = data["values"]["events"]
        event_data = []
        for event in events:
            event_data.append({
                "event_name": event["event_name"],
                "event_preview_url": event["event_preview_url"],
                "detail_url": event["detail_url"],
                "location": event["location"]
            })
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.city,
            {
                'type': 'send_event_data',
                'event_data': event_data
            }
        )

    async def send_event_data(self, event):
        event_data = event['event_data']
        await self.send(json.dumps({
            'event_data': event_data
        }))
```

###### routing.py:

```python
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/<str:city>/', consumers.EventConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

###### fashionShows/urls.py:

```python
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('events/<str:city>/', views.events, name='events'),
]
```

###### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def events(request, city):
    return render(request, 'events.html', {'city': city})
```

###### asgi.py:

```python
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'semWork.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        get_asgi_application(),
    ),
    "websocket": URLRouter(
        fashionShows.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ),
})
```